# Sidecar nav not displaying on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have an internal static site used for help desk ticket submission. I am having an issue where the slide out sidecar nav menu for mobile works in Chrome and Firefox but does not display on Safari, the javascript works and the menu slides out, but the actual content does not display. I at one point had this debugged but have seemingly reencountered it and have not been able to get it resolved. If anyone would take a few moments and could find a fix I'd definitely appreciate it as your typical stretched thin IT admin at a nonprofit. Thank you in advance for your help.

https://help.bccandp.org